# Remove the common elements from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns. One with 400 elements, and one with 600 elements. 400 of the 600 elements in the second list are in the first list. I want to remove all of them and just end up with a 200 elements list.

Set difference.

How can I achieve this in Excel?

Comment: So you want to "clean" the larger list??

Comment: Yes, we have 2 lists. One with places to visit, and one with places which we have already visited. They are on two different pages of an excel book, we want to remove all the places we have already visited from the list of places we still have to visit. I am sorry if this sounds dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your "400" list in column `A` (sheet "realizada") and "600" list in column `B` (sheet "completa"):

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rngToDel As Range, c As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("realizada").Range("A:A")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("completa")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each c In .Range("B1:B" & lastrow)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng, 0)) Then
                If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDel = c
                Else
                    Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, c)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    rngToDel.Select
    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

Comment: The two columns are in two different sheets, list A is called realizada and has 400 elements, list B is called completa and has the 600 elements. I need to clean 'completa' using the data from realizada, how can I modify your code to suit that. It seems like it only works with columns in the same sheet.